# How can i update image with tkinter slider (scale) value in python?

Tags: python, image-processing, tkinter, slider

I'm a beginner in python. All i want to do is create a simple GUI that implements basic Digital Image processing Algorithms. 
I want to adjust brightness of an image with tkinter slider. but this is not working and i am clueless as i'm just beginner. I am expecting the scale widget callback to do some brightness adjustment work but due too some reason the call back is not being invoked.

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter as tk
import Image
import ImageTk
import numpy as np
import tkFileDialog

class DIP(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent) 
        self.parent = parent        
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.parent.title("DIP Algorithms- Simple Photo Editor")
        self.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = 1)

        menubar = tk.Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu = menubar)

        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, border = 25)
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, border = 25)
        self.label1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        self.label2.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

        # File Menu
        fileMenu = tk.Menu(menubar)
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "File", menu = fileMenu)

        # Menu Item for Open Image
        fileMenu.add_command(label = "Open", command = self.onOpen)        

        # Basic menu
        basicMenu = tk.Menu(menubar)        
        menubar.add_cascade(label = "Basic", menu = basicMenu)

        # Menu Item for image negative
        basicMenu.add_command(label = "Negative", command = self.onNeg)

        #menu for brightness
        basicMenu.add_command(label = "Brightness", command = self.onBrghtness)

    def onBrghtness(self):
        #Image Brightness Adjustment Menu callback
        brgTk=tk.Tk()
        self.brgSc = tk.Scale( brgTk, from_=-50, to=50, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=self.adjBright, length=200 ,width=10, sliderlength=15)
        self.brgSc.pack(anchor=tk.CENTER)

    def adjBright(self):
        print self.brgSc #***here how can i get slider value, this callback is not being invoked***???

    def onNeg(self):
        #Image Negative Menu callback
        self.I2 = 255-self.I;
        self.im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(self.I2))
        photo2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.im)
        self.label2.configure(image=photo2)
        self.label2.image = photo2 # keep a reference!

    def setImage(self):
        self.img = Image.open(self.fn)
        self.I = np.asarray(self.img)
        l, h = self.img.size
        text = str(2*l+100)+"x"+str(h+50)+"+0+0"
        self.parent.geometry(text)
        photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        self.label1.configure(image = photo)
        self.label1.image = photo # keep a reference!

    def onOpen(self):
        #Open Callback
        ftypes = [('Image Files', '*.tif *.jpg *.png')]
        dlg = tkFileDialog.Open(self, filetypes = ftypes)
        filename = dlg.show()
        self.fn = filename
        #print self.fn #prints filename with path here
        self.setImage()

    #def onError(self):
        #box.showerror("Error", "Could not open file")    


def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    DIP(root)
    root.geometry("320x240")
    root.mainloop()  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

At the code where i mentioned the problem, the callback is failed because it says something like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args) 
TypeError: adjBright() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

Please do help, i know it may be stupid type of question to ask, but i'm just beginner and i hope i'll have deep understanding of PYTHON with time...

Comment: What version of Python are you running? I am getting `AttributeError: DIP instance has no attribute 'initUI'` error when trying to run it on 2.7.3.

Comment: @Fenikso that is just improper tabbing.

Comment: What exactly is your intention with this interface ? Do you want the `Scale` widget to appear only after you click on the menu item "brightness" ? Is it supposed to disappear at any time ?

Comment: @mmgp - Oh, sure. I did not notice. I have fixed the formatting for you. When you notice a mistake in your question, you can always  go and edit it.

Comment: Oh man, sorry. Obviously my comment about editing goes to @bistaumanga. I have somehow mistaken your identities. It was so early in the morning :-). So just ... never mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in call return
>   self.func(*args) TypeError: adjBright() takes exactly 1 argument (2
>   given)

You are getting this error because the scale callback is always passed the new value of the scale. Since you define `adjBright` to only have `self` as an argument, Tkinter throws an error. Unfortunately, this seems to be a somewhat under-documented feature of Tkinter.

Add another argument to `adjBright`, then you don't have to worry about fetching the new value:

```
def adjBright(self, new_value):
    print "the slider value is", new_value
```